# Power BI - Bar chart with one bar per logical column in table

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart

I have a table of things, and multiple true/false columns of attributes for that thing.

[image]

I want to make a bar chart with one bar for each attribute, and the value being a count of Thing IDs where the attribute is TRUE:

[image]

I'm sure it's simple but I'm having trouble, and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Power Query editor, you can pivot the columns of the attributes.
Select the attribute columns and click on tab transform on Pivot column.

you will get:
ThingID | Attribute | Value

then you can add a conditional column to count the TRUE.
If value equals TRUE then 1 else 0

Then make a chart in PowerBI and your Axis is the Attribute column and the Values is your count column and your there.

Comment: Does it matter that my table has millions of rows? For some reason millions of columns sounds worse to me, but maybe it makes no difference...

Comment: If you could change your data on input, it would be better offcourse.
Perhaps you can already filter your dataset on true for example? 

It would work by pivoting, but the performance really depends on your datamodelling.
Sorry cannot give an exact answer, it depends on your situation.

Comment: I think I misunderstood; after actually trying it this is absolutely the answer. Just to be more exact, I selected the attribute columns and clicked "Unpivot Columns"